# How to resolve this "at Object.<anonymous> " error in jest.js

Tags: jestjs

I have lots of global objects and say a function which is to be tested but when I run npm test i get 
at Object. (index.js:2:1)
at Object. (index.test.js:1:1)
this error 
this error points at the object "." of gblob.aobj={}; 
for simplicity sake i have created a index.js and index.test.js file ,im new to jest.js

**note: im working on SPA: single page application where this variable is created in another js**

index.js

```
    gblob.aobj={};
    function sum(a, b) {
    return a + b;
    }
    module.exports = sum;
```

"""
"""
index.test.js

```
   const sum = require('./index');

   test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
   expect(a.hy()).toBe(3);
   });
```

"""
"""
package.json if i need to add something here

```
    {
     "name": "my-app",
     "version": "1.0.0",
     "description": "",
     "main": "index.js",
     "scripts": {
     "test": "jest"
   },
    " author": "",
   "license": "ISC",
   "devDependencies": {
   "jest": "^24.7.1"
  }
  }
```

"""

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you are saying your test is failing because the global `gblob` doesn't exist when `index.js` runs.

You can fix that by creating a global `gblob` using the Node's [`global`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global).

If you create `global.gblob` at the beginning of your test then it will be available when your code runs:

index.test.js

```js
global.gblob = {};  // <= create the global "gblob"

const sum = require('./index');  // <= now require index.js

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: thanks for the help ,but i tried require on that object by exporting it in other file it worked :)

Comment: cool, glad to hear it's working.  Go ahead and create an answer that details what worked so any future viewers of the question can see how you were able to resolve the issue. @KarthikRao